# Buy $20$ tickets at once or $1$ ticket each for $20$ days?

Tags: probability

This question was recently asked by a user, but the question was deleted for some reason. But, it piqued my interest.

Question:

> There's a lottery where we have to guess correctly the number from $1$ to $100$.

The dilemma:

> There are $2$ options in front of us:
> A. Buy $20$ tickets at once.
> B. Buy $1$ ticket for each of the $20$ days.

The expected chances of winning for both are $\frac{20}{100}$.

Is there no "smarter" choice among the $2$? Please help.

Comment: Some insight was provided by @JMoravitz but didn't read it full as I was trying to edit the post.

Comment: Is the lottery held every day? Or every $20$ days?

Comment: @K.defaoite every day

Comment: 20 at once is better then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choices are not equivalent in their chance of winning. Playing sequentially, the chance of winning at least once is the complement of losing every day, or $1 - 0.99^{20}$, which is only 18.2% - less than the chance of winning exactly once by playing all 20 tickets on the same day. The sequential-buying approach changes in value if you account for winning multiple times, which cannot occur when playing multiple numbers on the same day.

Think about it this way - if you play all 100 numbers on a single day, you are guaranteed to win, but that certainly is not the case if you play one number every day for 100 days.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. +1. I slightly edited the question to include the word "expected" which I forgot previously. Any comments on that?

Comment: @InanimateBeing I think you are trying to refer to the "expected value" of playing, which combines your *probability* of winning with the *amount* you win. Playing sequentially allows you to win multiple times with low probability, balancing out the lower likelihood of winning once, to yield the same expected value. But this is *not* the same as the "expected chance of winning" which only respects your likelihood of winning and not the amount you win. Buying all 100 tickets on one day gives you an expected 100% chance of winning, buying 1 ticket for each of 100 days does not.

Comment: Alright, nice, thanks for the explanation.